# Leaflet drag scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, leaflet, development

My leaflet map is between a navigation bar and a chart displayed underneath. Unfortunately after recently incorporating leaflet-1.0-beta-2 my responsive layout is not working out on mobile devices because the tap: false solution for scroll dragging under map to see graph is not working anymore like 0.7.5. It seems like the issue has been noted on github, but I was wondering if anyone has found a way around this issue? I really wanted to keep the newest version of leaflet because most plug-ins are starting to migrate towards the new revision + fractional zoom.

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4051